# Guzzle: how to send a file and a second text field?

Tags: php, guzzle

I must simulate the sending of a form which has

- a file selector
- a text input

I'm sending the file  using this snippet

```
$response =  $this->getClient()->request(
                $method,
                $endpoint,
                [
                   'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data' ],
                   'multipart' => [
                      [
                           'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                           'name'     => 'file _name.tiicsti',
                           'contents' => 'hello my content',
                           'filename' => 'filename.txt',
                      ]
                   ]
                ]
            )

;
```

It works.

My question is: **how to send a text field in addition to my file?**

Comment: It’s covered in the documentation: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#sending-form-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !

I am surprise that headers is not needed. Probably Guzzle makes some magic

```
    $response =  $this->getClient()->request(
            $method,
            $endpoint,
            'multipart' => [
                  [
                      'name'        => 'text-field-name',
                      'contents'    => 'text field value'
                  ],
                  [

                       'name'     => 'file _name.tiicsti',
                       'contents' => 'hello my content',
                       'filename' => 'filename.txt',
                  ]
               ]
            ]
        )

    ;
```

Comment: Your text field needs to be an array element within the `multipart` key. Like demonstrated in the part of the documentation I linked you to.